# Using rasterio to rasterize vector data to a GCP referenced image

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio, rasterization, sentinel-1, ground-control

I am working with Sentinel-1 SAR images of a coastal area in ground range geometry (GRD product), which is defined by a geolocation grid of 10×21 ground control points. For further analysis, I need to mask out the land pixels.

For now I am using `rasterio.warp.reproject` to reproject the whole image to a CRS, where I can then use `rasterio.features.rasterize` to rasterize a land mask.

However, I would prefer to rasterize the land mask to the original image in ground range geometry. Is this possible with using rasterio or other python libraries (or command line tools)?

Any thoughts or references on this are welcome!